# Bootstrap: Padding top and width not working, but padding-bottom is

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```
 <div class="container-fluid border">


      <a href="#" class="name"> Vamsi Krishna Pappusetti</a>
 </div>
```

`width` and `padding` top of "name" class do not work.

Comment: A few things. Which version of Bootstrap are you using? It would be helpful to see your CSS code as there could be errors there. If you're using Bootstrap 4x, there are inline helper classes that could get you out of this bind.

Comment: I got it. Thanks though

Comment: Glad you could fix it. You should post the solution here, or mark one of the current answers as the right one, so that others can benefit from this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make a wild guess here, because you're not posting much relevant CSS. But... I'd bet the problem is that you're trying to set the padding and width of an inline element, such as a. If you haven't already, add `display:inline-block` or `display: block` to `.name`.

If this doesn't work, do provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example where others can reproduce the problem and diagnose it.

UPDATE: Based on your .name CSS:

```css
.name { color:#FFFFFF; background-color: #4AAAA5; padding-bottom: 20px; width:500px; padding-top: 20px; font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;}

.nameBlock {color:#FFFFFF; background-color: #4AAAA5; padding-bottom: 20px; width:500px; padding-top: 20px; font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="container-fluid border">

Without inline block
      <a href="#" class="name"> Vamsi Krishna Pappusetti</a>
      </div>
 <div class="container-fluid border">

With inline block
      <a href="#" class="nameBlock"> Vamsi Krishna Pappusetti</a>
      </div>
```

Comment: This is my CSS: .name {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color: #4AAAA5;
   
    
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    width:500px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;

Comment: Did you try adding display: inline-block or block? It should make a difference if there's no parent CSS affecting your link. Always keep in mind that you're using Cascading Style Sheets, and that there are tons of elements that can affect one little line. Diagnosing these issues normally requires reading all of the CSS.